# В yii2 на сайте сломалась вёрстка страниц контакта, регистрации и входа при добавлении widgets menu

Tags: yii2, bootstrap

Приветствую, помогите пожалуйста при добавлении "виджет меню" на сайте сломалась вёрстка страниц контакта, регистрации и входа.. Вот код моего виджета:

```
<?php $menuItems = array_filter([
                ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['/site/index'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
                ['label' => 'О Нас', 'url' => ['/site/about'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
                ['label' => 'Контакты', 'url' => ['/site/contact'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item',]],
                Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '':
                    ['label' => 'Управление пользователями', 'url' => ['/user/admin'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']],
                Yii::$app->user->isGuest ?
                    ['label' => 'Вход', 'url' => ['/user/security/login'], 'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item']] :
                    ['label' => 'Выход (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                        'url' => ['/user/security/logout'],
                        'options' => ['class' => 'menu-item'],
                        'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']],
            ]);
            echo Menu::widget([
                'items' => $menuItems,
                'options' => ['class' => 'reset', 'role' => 'navigation'],

            ]); ?>
        </nav>
```

Почему не применились стили web/assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добрый вечер.

Для начала проверьте исходный код страницы. Возможно не туда вставили код виджета.

Очистите директорию web/assets, удалите все файлы внутри директории.
Проверьте, подключился ли css для виджета, если у Вас отдельные стили для этого виджета.

В конфигурационном файле можно настроить assetManager, установите параметр linkAssets в true

```
   'assetManager' => [
       'linkAssets' => true,
       'appendTimestamp' => true
   ],
```

Это нужно на момент разработки, чтобы файлы ресурсов обновлялись при каждом обновлении страницы.

Comment: Спасибо огромное действительно я не добавила в исходном коде div с классом wrap